# VBA Excel conditional formatting IF - THEN date

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I want to do conditionnal formating with the following rules:

If a cell of my colum B is purple then apply the following rules on my column A that contains dates:

`=TODAY()-A1>1<31`  - color Pink
`=TODAY()-A1>30<61` - color Green

you get the point

However, if the content of my cell in the column B is blue, then I want my cell in the column A to be blue as well.
I'm at the point that I dont even know if my formula is right. Thnks

Comment: I imagine this would be very difficult, even if you use something like here (http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=82173&s=56aa8f3229b7c3d6856ecf88d1120bde&p=406694#post406694). Curious to see if anyone can easily solve this.

Comment: What is the rule to color column B purple?  Otherwise you would need a UDF

Comment: The column B is changed manually - it indicates if the bill is paid or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UDF in a conditional formatting rule:

```
Function IsYellow(c) As Boolean
    IsYellow = (c.Interior.Color = vbYellow)
End Function
```

Updates will only get triggered when the sheet recalculates though.

Comment: Do you know if vbYellow includes different shades of yellow? Or a predefined rgb or ColorIndex?

Comment: It's a pre-defined Long value. That's always the trouble with code relying on checking the color of something: there's no constant for "looks yellow-ish" !

Comment: lol that's exactly what I was worried about. Either way, +1 for the solution. That's what I would have went with.

Answer (score 0):

An option for this is to go the VBA route, which would apply "conditional formatting" to cells as you go. For example:

```
For A_row = 1 To 100
  If Range(A_row, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = my_color_index Then
    Range(A_row, "A").NumberFormat = my_custom_format
    'add desired custom number formats here
  End If
Next
```